# Import error with named tuple and Mapping

Tags: python, importerror, python-3.11, python-collections

I have trying to fix an import error with the `requests` library in Python 3.11. This is to run a Discord bot that I have created. My original error is given as `ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'` and in response I have tried changing a line from `from collections import namedtuple, Mapping` to `from collections.abc import namedtuple, Mapping`. This has not fixed my original error. The new error created is the traceback given below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python projects\newer Vorpal\main.py", line 4, in <module>
from game import game, shopping
  File "E:\python projects\newer Vorpal\game.py", line 10, in <module>
from monsters import createmonsters
  File "E:\python projects\newer Vorpal\monsters.py", line 2, in <module>
import requests
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
from .connection import (
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 39, in <module>
from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .connection import is_connection_dropped
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 3, in <module>
from .wait import wait_for_read
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\wait.py", line 1, in <module>
from .selectors import (
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\selectors.py", line 14, in <module>
from collections.abc import namedtuple, Mapping

ImportError: cannot import name 'namedtuple' from 'collections.abc' (C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\collections\abc.py)
```

Comment: What's the original problem? Your attempted solution obviously isn't working since `collections.abc.namedtuple` doesn't exist. You can confirm that with the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html).

Comment: @wjandrea My original problem is an import error with mapping. The error is as follows: `ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'`

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include that

Comment: Please post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`namedtuple` is located in the [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) module, `Mapping` -- in the [collections.abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) module. Starting from python 3.10 the line `from collections import Mapping` throws an error. You should separate the two imports, like so:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
from collections import namedtuple
```

Answer (score 2):

You must be using an outdated version of `urllib3`. This issue was [fixed in Feb 2018](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/1325/files) and then [the `selectors` module was removed entirely](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/commit/9782e1f866aa6d0d176dce8678aee448aeb492dd#diff-563b94aba03f2a86278fac7fafec9cf91849ecf87a2b2e08741dd382016bc1fb), [before version 1.23](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/commits/1.23/urllib3/util), released in Jun 2018.